# Problema em renderização

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Na minha tela de cadastro tenho 2 botões: **Salvar** e **Voltar**.
Caso eu esteja editando algum registro, é habilitado o botão **Novo**.
Meu problema está quando clico neste botão **Novo** a tela dá o refresh mas o que eu quero é que limpe os dados para um cadastro novo. Um help por favor?

Método que é acionado quando clico no botão:

```
public void novo(){
    if (nature == null){
        nature = new Nature();
    } else{
        nature = null;
    }
    }
```

Código do botão:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{habilidademb.novo}" value="Novo" ajax="false" update="cadastro" rendered="#{naturemb.nature.id != null}" styleClass="separadorBotoes"/>
```

Comment: O problema é que você não pode marcar ajax="false", você está exatamente fazendo com que a tela dê refresh. tire essa opção, por default o jsf já deixa o ajax como true.

Comment: Outra coisa, no seu método novo(), você não precisa fazer nenhuma verificação, apenas deixe nature = new Nature();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido. Eram 2 problemas:

- O nome do mb estava errado.
- No método `novo()` precisava instanciar o objeto ao final.

  public void novo() {
          if (nature == null) {
              nature = new Nature();
          } else {
              nature = null;
              nature = new Nature();
          }
      }